# Scheduling a long task in GCMNetworkManager

Tags: android, background, gcm-network-manager, gcmtaskservice

I am using a `GCMNetworkManager` to schedule a background task. My task is to download content from the server which sometimes could take even upto 7 minutes.

1. In this case, will the `GCMTaskManager` hold the wake lock this long? If not, how do I handle the situation?
2. Can I start a service from the `onRunTask()` method in my class extending from `GcmTaskService`? Will it throw an `IllegalStateException` in `Android 8.0 (Oreo)` if the application is in background when the task runs?